# I need to upgrade ingress-nginx from v1.1.1 to v1.9.4 as i use it as a helm chart inside my infrastructure? how to know the break changes?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-gcp, ingress-nginx

I need to upgrade ingress-nginx helm chart from 4.0.16 to 4.8.3 as ingress-controller version will be upgraded from  v1.1.1 to 1.9.4.
I need to know the break changes from version to version as i got lost in github releases.
if there any docs for ingress-nginx talked about the break changes between versions please put comment?.

I try to read changes from https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases?expanded=true&page=3&q=controller-v1.1.1 but i lost the way.
i expect to find the break changes in docs like this https://cert-manager.io/docs/releases/upgrading/upgrading-1.7-1.8.